# How do I scrape data in <canvas> element with python or javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, chart.js

I want to scrape data from sites like [this (stat game of the game I play)](https://stats.warbrokers.io/players/i/5d2ead35d142affb05757778) where an interactive chart is being rendered in the `<canvas>` element and does not show any data as a scrape-able HTML element.
Inspecting the HTML, the page appear to use [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org).

Though help in python is preferred, if I really need to use some javascript, that would be fine too.

Plus, I would like to avoid methods that require extra files such as phantomjs but again, if that's the only way, please be generous enough to share it.

Comment: For python you can use selenium

Comment: can you share url of the page ?

Comment: @IainShelvington I have no clue how to use selenium to scrape data from canvas.
I am a noob in web scraping;;;

Comment: @AleksandarCiric you can just click it but OK here is it
https://stats.warbrokers.io/players/i/5d2ead35d142affb05757778

Comment: you can not scrape canvas because it is like image, so you need to use some software for image recognition                                                                                        but you can find all the data inside canvas on you page, for example in this tag //div[@class='playerStatPage']/following-sibling::script                                                     or in image elements, for example this //div[@id='ribbons-sm']/div[@class='ribbon-wrapper']

Comment: and you don't need javascript

Comment: "and you don't need javascript" the best thing I can hear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to to solve this is through checking out the `<script>` of the page in the page source around line 1050, which is actually where the charts are initialized. There's a recurring pattern in the initialization process of the charts, wherein the canvas elements are queried one by one to get their contexts, followed by the variables that offers the labels and statistics of the charts.

This solution covers using node.js, at least the latest version with the following modules:

- [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) for querying elements in the DOM
- [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for sending an http request to get the page source.
- [abstract-syntax-tree](https://www.npmjs.com/package/abstract-syntax-tree) to get a javascript object tree representation of the script that we wish to scrape.

Here's the [solution](https://repl.it/repls/AlphanumericScholarlyDrivers) and the source code below:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const axios = require('axios');

const { parse, each, find } = require('abstract-syntax-tree');

async function main() {

    // get the page source
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        'https://stats.warbrokers.io/players/i/5d2ead35d142affb05757778'
    );

    // load the page source with cheerio to query the elements
    const $ = cheerio.load(data);

    // get the script tag that contains the string 'Chart.defaults'
    const contents = $('script')
        .toArray()
        .map(script => $(script).html())
        .find(contents => contents.includes('Chart.defaults'));

    // convert the script content to an AST
    const ast = parse(contents);

    // we'll put all declarations in this object
    const declarations = {};

    // current key
    let key = null;

    // iterate over all variable declarations inside a script
    each(ast, 'VariableDeclaration', node => {

        // iterate over possible declarations, e.g. comma separated
        node.declarations.forEach(item => {

            // let's get the key to contain the values of the statistics and their labels
            // we'll use the ID of the canvas itself in this case..
            if(item.id.name === 'ctx') { // is this a canvas context variable?
                // get the only string literal that is not '2d'
                const literal = find(item, 'Literal').find(v => v.value !== '2d');
                if(literal) { // do we have non- '2d' string literals?
                    // then assign it as the current key
                    key = literal.value;
                }
            }

            // ensure that the variable we're getting is an array expression
            if(key && item.init && item.init.type === 'ArrayExpression') {

                // get the array expression
                const array = item.init.elements.map(v => v.value);

                // did we get the values from the statistics?
                if(declarations[key]) {

                    // zip the objects to associate keys and values properly
                    const result = {};
                    for(let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
                        result[array[index]] = declarations[key][index];
                    }
                    declarations[key] = result;

                    // let's make the key null again to avoid getting
                    // unnecessary array expression
                    key = null;

                } else {
                    // store the values
                    declarations[key] = array;
                }
            }

        });

    });

    // logging it here, it's up to you how you deal with the data itself
    console.log(declarations);

}

main();
```

Comment: I like your intelligent response. is this python or Javascript? whichever one please can you do step by step tutorial video on this. I am working on similar project and am having problem with it. @ryeballar